# React-tabs: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null, when switching back to main tab?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs, react-tabs

I have a `Main.js` which is a React class that consolidates other React classes. This works well, but I now want to have three tabs; The first containing the aforementioned `Main.js`, but the others containing different things.

Using `react-tabs` I've successfully managed to get it done. There are three tabs as created here:

```
<Tabs>
    <TabList>
        <Tab>Main</Tab>
        <Tab>Second</Tab>
        <Tab>Third</Tab>
    </TabList>
     <TabPanel>
        Main goes here.
     </TabPanel>
     <TabPanel>
        Second goes here.
     </TabPanel>
     <TabPanel>
        Third goes here.
     </TabPanel>
</Tabs>
```

The `Main` tab renders and displays just fine. However, if I click to, say, the `Second` tab, and then back to `Main`, I will get the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null`.

I see where I get the error; namely the first time data from `this.state` is being used.

What is going wrong? Is it because it is trying to re-render the entire `Main` component instead of saving the state?

Edit: Here are some pointers to how state is managed in this Main component.

```
getInitialState: function() {
        return { data : {
            info : {},
            hist : {},
            grouped : {},
            cars : {},
            user : "",
            map :  {},
        }}},
```

We instantiate the values above as empty.

When component mounts, it's populated as such:

```
componentDidMount : function() {
    this.loadData();
    setInterval(this.loadData, 60000);
}
```

Where it'll load every 60 seconds.

The loadData function is something along these lines:

```
loadData : function() {
        console.info("Loading data.. ");
                $.ajax({
        url: this.props.prefix_url + "/api",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.info("Received backend data ");
            this.setState({data: data }); // Attach data to the empty values
// .. Goes on
```

Comment: can you show the code of main component ?

Comment: It's super long. Basically I declare the data as empty arrays or objects in getInitialState, then make an Ajax call to retrieve it in componentDidMount. Is that the issue you think?

Comment: yes, i think situation is like this: `a: {}`, then you are fetching the a by `ajax` call and using `a.data` somewhere, just put the check before using `a.data` or hold the `rendering` of component until you didn't get the **response**.

Comment: That must be it indeed. How would you hold rendering depending on a function outside of the scope? I load data with `this.loadData();`.. Should I check this for a boolean value then?

Comment: To extend what Mayank said, you need to accommodate the async nature of your data fetch. It would'nt hurt to perhaps have some sort of {dataLoading: (true / false)} state, that you can use as an indicator for when it is okay to access .data. Just set the default state of dataLoading to true, and then set it to false when the fetch is complete. You can then implement some logic in your render function that only renders .data when dataLoading == false.

Comment: If your data is being fetched in a parent component, you can simply pass a dataLoading prop to your tabs component, which can then be used in the same way.

Comment: I tried doing an onClick function which invokes this.loadData() but that produced the samae error.

Comment: Im afraid you will have to post some more code in order to get to the root cause of that error. Post your onclick function. Post the code for this.loadData(). show us the render function that connects the parent component to this tabs component. Give us some code and we will figure it out.

Comment: I've added some sample code. As for the render method of the component, it pretty much just returns a bunch of divs that contain components from other React classes. Then I map the data by saying, taking from the example above, `<importedClass data=this.state.data.info />`

Comment: I guess the problem is that the state of the Tab is lost once another one is opened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add `forceRenderTabPanel={true}` to the tabs as such: `<Tabs forceRenderTabPanel={true}>` , this will keep track of the state across all three tabs and not just the one you are on.